# MySQL Table Setup for today, yesterday, monthly logs

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I am working on a PHP / MySQL stat logging program and am trying to find the best MySQL DB Structure for it.

There is a part where visitors will be able to see up to the date stats (i.e the latest 20  entries) but also will be able to see today's overall, yesterday's overall, last 7 days overall and last 30 days overall stats.

From the data I'm pulling the real-time stats will be updated every 60 seconds with at least 10 new entries per update.

Is my logic correct to setup two tables ... one to act as "today's" stats and another to act as the overall archive ... like:

> **todays_stats**
>   id
>   from_url
>   entry_date
>
> **overall_stats**
>   id
>   from_url
>   entry_date

Then double insert for each new entry but truncate the todays_stats at midnight every night via a cron job?

Or is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: one table would be better, then use a query to get what data you want. you can use GROUP BY to get daily or weekly or any other stats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your daily stat row count, whether to delete historical data, and how much indexes you has. We need to delete historical data and has 7~8 indexes with large amount of stat data, so we separate data into daily tables and write stored procedures to fetch data(last day, last 7 day, last 30 day etc). Dropping table is much more faster than `DELETE FROM table WHERE index=6-month-old-data`

Answer (score 0):

I think best way is to be keep one table that will hold the current data set, then you will have separate table for overall stats and at midnight you will insert all data from current to overall table with

```
INSERT INTO `overall` SELECT * FROM `current`
```

query. Then you will truncate the current table after successful data copying.

Comment: Thanks Alex! Going to give that a try tonight with the sample data and see how it performs.